# How To Combine File Names From find Output Into A String

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

Using `find` it is trivial to lookup all files with a particular pattern:

```
find . -name \*.jar
```

**How do I combine the results of that command (e.g. all of the filenames) into a single string separated by a `:`?**

The expected result would look something like:

```
"./foo.jar:./bar.jar"
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find . -name \*.jar -printf '%P:'`

Comment: You might add `| sed 's/:$//'` to get rid of the final `:` or `| sed 's/:$/\n/'` to have a final newline...

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name \*.jar | tr '\n' ':'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.jar' | paste -sd : -
```

But that wouldn't work properly if there were file or directory names that contain newline characters.

To work around that, on a GNU system, you can use:

```
find . -name '*.jar' -print0 | paste -zsd: | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Of course, if your file or directory names have `:` characters, there's not much you can do about it, though you could tell `find` to skip them:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*:*' -prune -o -name '*.jar' -print0 |
  paste -zsd: | tr '\0' '\n'
```

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
jar_files=(**/*.jar~*:*(ND))
printf '%s\n' ${(j/:/)jar_files}
```

Comment: I love how you always say : It will not work if there'e new line in your file name. I feel like fs devs should have avoid this to avoid so many troubleshoot.

Comment: it's an excellent point about filenames containing the delimiter, here, though.